# Javascript Character encoding issue when string contains special characters "&amp;acirc;" , " &amp;#128;" , "&amp;#148;"

Tags: javascript, encoding, iconv

I have a string with some special character encoding like below

string = "Test data description &acirc;&#128;&#148; for validations".

When rendering this string on the html page set to utf-8 it displays â€” character instead of actual character. I tried using npm packages iconv-lite , iconv , legacy-encoding and few other but couldn't make it work. Can someone suggest a solution for this.

I have tried below libraries but did not had luck.

```
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
var Iconv  = require('iconv').Iconv;
var iconv = new Iconv('CP1252', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT');
var buffer = iconv.convert('Test data description &amp;acirc;&amp;#128;&amp;#148; for validations');
str = Buffer.from(buffer).toString(); 


var legacyEncoding = require("legacy-encoding")
var buffer = legacyEncoding.encode('Test data description &amp;acirc;&amp;#128;&amp;#148; for validations', 'utf8', {'mode': 'html'});
var text = legacyEncoding.decode(buffer, 'iso-8859-1');
```

Comment: Those are "html entities".

Comment: @RickJames could you please elaborate more on your answer ?

Comment: Start by throwing out all the conversion stuff.  Get rid of the double-encoding (`&amp;` maps to `&`).  Show more of how you got to this mess.